# Acceleration of Light when it moves through different medium

Tags: optics, visible-light, acceleration, speed-of-light, refraction

Assume three mediums with refractive index $a$ , $b$ , $c$ where is $a$ for Air and $b$  and $c$ are some different medium. Relation between them is $a<c<b$. As Light enters Via point $P$ and $Q$ it's velocity changes while travelling through mediums. Then what is rate of change of velocity at $P$ and $Q$ respectively?[image]

Comment: Just as a brief aside, the path of the light should bend towards the axis from a to b, and away from the axis from b to c.

Comment: Look up Cherenkov radiation.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of light is not differentiable at the interface. On the macro scale, the velocity is discontinuous. If you zoom in to the scale of a single atom looking for a continuous curve, you'll get a superposition of two c-propagating electromagnetic waves: one the original light, the other an induced wave from the atom being displaced by the electromagnetic wave.  The interference pattern very near the atom looks like a beam of light which travels at $c/n$. Far from the atom the induced wave is negligible. In the middle distance, it looks like a c-propagating wave with some interference.